# Inter-app communication in Android: How to end an application (App B) and return data to caller app (App A)

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have two applications. `App A` and `App B`.

`App A` is the main application. `App A` can open up `App B`.
`App B` on the other hand, is a standalone application with 3 activities.

> AppB.FirstActivity = Let's the user select items from the list
>   AppB.SecondActivity = Perform processing based on selected items
>   AppB.ThirdActivity = This is where the user can accept the results or
>   retry 
>                            processing

`App A` would like to receive information based on `AppB.ThirdActivity`'s output.

I tried using `startActivityForResult()` to call the `AppB.FirstActivity` of `App B` (from `App A`) but to no avail, all I get in `onActivityResult` is a null data.

How do I get the result of `AppB.ThirdActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best scenario is open another app over `intent` message.

When second app finish its work, on `onDestroy` send another `intent` to run the first app. The `intent` should have right flags to keep the right state of the first app.

First app

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("custom.action");
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="custom.action" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Second app, target activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.home.androiddemo", "com.home.androiddemo.MainActivity"));
    intent.setAction("custom.android");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    // TODO pass necessary outcome

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="custom.action" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks mate. I'm exploring intent messages because of this at the moment. However, I can't seem to receive the right intent in `App A.onResume`